# My first C program - Game of Life: printf segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm having issues with my first C program, a version of Conway's Game of Life for my C/C++ course. I wrote it and got it to compile with GCC, but I'm getting stuck trying to chase segmentation faults. Specifically, right now my issue is in my print function. I included main() as well in case the issue is related to it. I left out the other functions as I don't see how they'd be relevant.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define  XMAX  240
#define  YMAX  80

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  int cycles  = 0;
  char current[XMAX][YMAX];
  char next[XMAX][YMAX];
  //first, fill current with all spaces
  int i,j;
    for( j=0; j< YMAX; j++){
      for( i = 0; i < XMAX; i++) {
        current[i][j] = ' ';
    }
  }
  //next, check if there are an even number of inputs
  //if there are, edit those cells in current
  if (argc > 1) {
    if (argc % 2 != 0) {
     int k;
     for(k = 0; k < argc-1; k+=2) {
     current[atoi(*argv[k])][atoi(*argv[k+1])] = 'O';
  }
 }

  //otherwise, we print an error message and quit.-
   else {
    printf("Invalid number of command line arguments, must be even");
    return;
}
}
//print starting configuration
  print(current, cycles);
//start recursive update method
  update(current, next, cycles);
}
```

The offending print function:

```
// method that prints world and number of cycles
void print(char world[XMAX][YMAX], int cycles) {
printf(cycles);
printf("\n");
// iterates through world printing everything
int i;
int j;
for( j = 0; j < YMAX; j++) {
  for( i = 0; i < XMAX; i++) {
    printf(world[i][j]);
    }
  //print a new line every time we jump down a row
  printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Here's the log from debugging. This happens before any output is produced.

```
Program received signal
SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7aa32ba in strchrnul () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff7aa32ba in strchrnul () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7a59cd2 in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7a64519 in printf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x000000000040092b in print (world=0x7fffffff9210, cycles=0) at game.c:48
#4  0x000000000040088b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde18) at game.c:34
(gdb) frame 3
#3  0x000000000040092b in print (world=0x7fffffff9210, cycles=0) at game.c:48
48            printf(world[i][j])  ;
(gdb) print i
$1 = 0
(gdb) print j
$2 = 0 
(gdb) print world[i][j]
$3 = -128 '\200'
(gdb) print sizeof(world)
$4 = 8 
(gdb) print sizeof(world[0])
$5 = 80
```

So, there's a few things I don't get. First, why I can access world[i][j] but printf can't? It can't just be an out of bounds error since both index values are still at 0, right?

Secondly, what does -128 '\200' signify, and why is it not a space character? Main was supposed to fill the array with spaces, so I might have messed up there.

Finally, what's going on with the size of the arrays? It's supposed to be 240 x 80, so why is one size 80 but the other is only 8?

I'm sure these are nauseatingly simple questions for some of you, so bear with me. I'm coming from a java background, so C is recognizable but just different enough to throw me off. Also, if more information is required, I can provide it.

Comment: `I don't see how they'd be relevant`. If you did, you wouldn't be getting a seg-fault in the first place, now would you?

Comment: When code compiles, does it do so without warnings?

Comment: `printf(world[i][j])`? `printf(cycles)`? That not even compilable. Did you just ignore compiler diagnostic messages?

Comment: It definitely had a bunch of warnings. I was going to go back and deal with them later, once I had core functionality complete, but I guess that might not have been the best strategy, at least for a language like C.

Comment: `argv[0]` is program name.

Comment: @RadLexus `if (argc % 2 != 0)` It is not directly related.  see `for(k = 0; k < argc-1; k+=2) {
     current[atoi(*argv[k])][atoi(*argv[k+1])] = 'O';`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: ... what can I say, the wrongly placed `else` threw me off. That and OP's haphazard indentures.

Comment: Also post your update function

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely in these lines:

```
printf(cycles);
printf(world[i][j]);
```

The thing is that the prototype of `printf` is:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...)
```

but you are passing an `int` and a  `char` as single arguments, not a `const char *`. This should have emitted a warning at compile time. Never ignore a warning!

If your compiler is not warning about this usage you should really add the all-warnings-on compiler option (`-Wall` in GCC, for example).

The solution is easy, use a format string:

```
printf("%d\n", cycles); // add the \n to the same format!
printf("%c", world[i][j]);
```

About your question:

> First, why I can access world[i][j] but printf can't? It can't just be an out of bounds error since both index values are still at 0, right?

The debugger `print` is not related to the function `printf`. The debugger knows the declared type of the typed expression; `printf` does not. That's what the format string is for.

> Secondly, what does -128 '\200' signify, and why is it not a space character? Main was supposed to fill the array with spaces, so I might have messed up there.

No idea. You are segfaulting, so the variables in the stack may be corrupted or something.

> Finally, what's going on with the size of the arrays? It's supposed to be 240 x 80, so why is one size 80 but the other is only 8?

`world` inside the function is not actually an array, but a pointer. Array declarations in function arguments are demoted to pointers, so `char world[XMAX][YMAX]` gets compiled as `char (*world)[YMAX]`. Thus, `sizeof(world)` is the size of a pointer. However, since it is a pointer to an array, `world[0]` is of type `char[YMAX], so`sizeof(world[0])`is`YMAX`.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you can not print a single character by using

```
printf(world[i][j])
```

because the first argument has to be a string. So it tries to interpret world[i][j] as string and searches for the first byte that is 0 (the string terminator in C) and therefore continues the search in memory areas that it is not allowed to access (therefore the segfault).

If you only want to print a single char, use

```
print("%c",world[i][j])
```

Answer (score 0):

The function printf is like this:

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

But you use:

```
printf(world[i][j]);
```

Did you mean to do it like this:

```
printf("%d", world[i][j]);
```

Also, this is wrong:

```
printf(cycles);
```